# How to see which tableView is on top

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have multiple tableViews stacked on top of each other, and I need to know programmatically which one is on top (the z axis).

Comment: Please explain your problem in more details.

Comment: Why have more than one table view? If you must have more than one, why not keep track of which one you move to the top of the z-axis?

Answer (score 1):

UIView siblings are stacked in the order in which they are added to their superview.

You can check with the following code:

View on top:  `parentView.subviews.lastObject`;

View at the bottom:  `parentView.subviews[0]`;

If you want a view to appear in front of all other views:

```
parentView.bringSubview(toFront: view)
```

You can use the zPosition property of the view's layer (it's a CALayer object) to change the z-index of the view.

```
theView.layer.zPosition = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Views’ z-order are determined by their ordering in their superview’s `subviews` array.

Given two siblings, A and B: B is on top if B’s index in the `subviews` array (belonging to their common parent) is greater than A’s index. This is true whether or not A and B's frames overlap.

NSArray responds to `indexOfObject:` which makes the test simple.